# Moving a draggable node to another layer

Tags: kineticjs, layer, swap

I have a problem with sawpping a group, which is draggable, from one layer to another layer.
When the group is swapped with "shape.moveTo(rightLayer)" it stops moving, altough it is still draggable.

You can check it with this little example, move the green box from the red box into to blue box.

Is there a problem with moving nodes to other layers while this node is draggable or make I some misstakes ?

Thx a lot ..

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> 
<head>

    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var stage;
var leftLayer;
var rightLayer;
function doOnLoad(){

    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "canvas",
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
    });

    // left layer & background
    leftLayer = new Kinetic.Layer(
        {
            id: 'leftLayer', x: 10, y: 10, width: 290, height: 300
        }
    );
    var leftBackground = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0, y: 0, width: leftLayer.width(), height: leftLayer.height(), fill: '#FBB'
    });


    // scaled, right layer & background
    rightLayer = new Kinetic.Layer(
        {
            id: 'rightLayer', x: 300,   y: 10, width: 590, height: 600
        }
    );
    var rightBackground = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0, y: 0, width: rightLayer.width(),  height: rightLayer.height(), fill: '#BBF'
    });
    rightLayer.scaleX(0.5);
    rightLayer.scaleY(0.5);

    // move group
    var moveGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 50, y: 50, id: 'MainGroup', width: 80, height: 80, draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
            return dragMainGroup(pos, this);
        }
    });
    var moveBox = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80, fill: '#0F0', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 2
    });     
    moveGroup.add(moveBox);

    leftLayer.add(leftBackground);
    leftLayer.add(moveGroup);

    rightLayer.add(rightBackground);

    stage.add(rightLayer);
    stage.add(leftLayer);
}

// separted function, will later be complex
function dragMainGroup(posOnStage, shape){
    var x = posOnStage.x; 
    var y = posOnStage.y;
    if(stage.getPointerPosition().x > 300){
        if(shape.parent != rightLayer){
            shape.moveTo(rightLayer);
            stage.draw();
        }
    }else{
        if(shape.parent != leftLayer){
            shape.moveTo(leftLayer);
            stage.draw();
        }
    }
    return {x:x, y:y};
}

</script>

</head>


<body bgcolor="#ffffff" onload="doOnLoad()">
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simply fix just reinit draging:

```
if(stage.getPointerPosition().x > 300){
    if(shape.parent != rightLayer){
        shape.moveTo(rightLayer);
        shape.startDrag();
        stage.draw();
    }
}else{
    if(shape.parent != leftLayer){
        shape.moveTo(leftLayer);
        shape.startDrag();
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/272ka/

**Note:**

Your object's positioning is really hard.
Group is positioning relative to parent. And you are setting x,y,width,height for layers. I think this is bad way. It is harder to understand were objects should be after moving. (if group have x = 10, layer have x = 10, then on screen group will have position at x = 20, if you are setting scale, it is more harder to understand were group should be). Just try to avoid this.

Comment: Thx for your Feedback, but that didn't help me on my new Project.

I have a lot off shapes which can be dragged into a "construction plane", here I may can take a layer, but this plane/layer can be pan and scaled by the user. I have made a function so that the layer clipped everthing when you zoom in or pan, the only Problem is the switch between the "selection-layer" and the final "construction-layer".

I take a look and post a solution if I find one.